Trouble restoring from iCloud Backup without old phone
My old iPhone died and I am trying to set up a replacement.  When I get to the "Transfer Your Apps & Data" step (see first picture below) I choose "From iCloud Backup" (because I don't have another phone to use).  I would expect that I would then be prompted to enter my Apple ID and password, but instead I get a prompt to "Use Another Device to Sign In".  But I don't have another device!  The "Continue" button is grayed out so I don't know what to do.  Surely this isn't how it's supposed to work, right?  What am I doing wrong here?  Or maybe a better question is:  Why is "Continue" greyed out, and what do I have to do to enable it?
 

What happens when you choose "Use Another Device to Sign In"?
